# Access child user control's property in parent user control

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, properties, public

I have included a user control in another statically following code :

---

place the folowing directive in the asp code of the parent page or
usercontrol:

`<%@ Register src="Name_of_your_child_control.ascx"
tagname="Name_of_your_child_control" tagprefix="uc1" %>`

use the following tag in the asp-code of the parent page/control:

`<uc1:Name_of_your_child_control ID="Name_of_your_child_control1"
runat="server" />`

.....
But the issue is...i am not able to access the public properties of user control which got included(child user control) in given user control(parent user control)...

Please help :(

Answer (score 5):

Say your usercontrol was this:

```
<%@ Control Inherits="Project.MyControl" Codebehind="MyControl.ascx.cs" %>
<asp:TextBox ID="TB" runat="server" />
```

Your control code-behind:

```
namespace Project 
{
  public partial class MyControl : UserControl
  {
    public string MyTextProperty
    {
      get { return TB.Text; }
      set { TB.Text = value; }
    }
  }
}
```

In your parent page that included the control, like this:

```
<%@ Register src="~/MyControl.ascx" tagname="MyControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<uc1:MyControl ID="MyControlID" runat="server" />
```

You can use that property in code:

```
MyControlID.MyTextProperty = "bob";
```

Comment: But ...for me it is coming as i can not access the property :(

Comment: @Anish - If you reference it as if it were there and compile, what error do you get?

Comment: Is ur parent page is also a user control ?

Parent Page
{
uc1
{
uc2
{
}
}


}

Comment: @Anish - You want to access the property from the Parent control's code-behind, or from the page's codebehind that contains the parent?

Comment: I have 2 user controls : uc1 and uc2
Also a parent page p1.
I have included uc1 inside p1.
Now i need to include uc2 inside uc1...and access uc2 property inside uc1

Comment: @Anish - If you follow my answer, just including the control in a UserControl instead of a page it should work just the same, you should be able to use `MyControlID.MyTextProperty` in the code-behind of the parent user control, what compile error do you get if you try?

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
Name_of_your_child_control1.PublicPropertyName
```

must work for your parent user control.

Answer (score 0):

Check the path and file names you are using, Anish.  You have something wrong.  Is Visual Studio telling you it can't find the control?  Is it failing at compile time?  Runtime?

Answer (score 0):

It's funny but whenever you add a property to a user control.

You need to register it again in the parent. So in your case,

Add a space at the end of this line and remove it again:
`$<% Register src="~/MyControl.ascx" tagname="MyControl" tagprefix="uc1" %>`

This will re - register the user control and you will be able to access new properties.